# Diffeomorphism between a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the annulus

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose $\gamma_1, \gamma_2:I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ are two simple closed and smooth curves. Suppose also that the images $\gamma_1(I)$ and $\gamma_2(I)$ are disjoint and $\gamma_1(I)=S^1$. Is it true that there exists a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\Phi(\gamma_1(I))=S^1$ and $\Phi(\gamma_2(I))=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 \big|\ \|x\|=2\}$ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "concentric circumferences"

Comment: I edited the question explaining better what I mean

Comment: I would guess this is not possible in general, unless we talk about $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\lbrace0\right\rbrace$. In particular you can not get $\gamma_2(I)$ outside of $\gamma_1(I)$ by applying $\phi$, because $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\gamma_1(I)$ consists of two components, which are not diffeomorphic to eachother. Further you do not have to assume that $\gamma_1(I)=S^1$, as you can always achieve this by applying your diffeomorphism by the [Jordan-Schoenflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem).

Comment: But if we talk about $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\lbrace0\right\rbrace$, then for two simple closed smooth curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\lbrace0\right\rbrace$ it is not true in general anymore, that there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ such that $\varphi\circ\gamma_1=\gamma_2$

Comment: However, by the Jordan curve Theorem we know that $\gamma_1(I)$ separates $\mathbb{R}^2$ into two components, one bounded and one unbounded. If $\gamma_2(I)$ lies in the bounded component we surely get some diffeomorphism mapping $\gamma_2(I)$ to $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \big|\ ||x||=\frac{1}{2}\}$ and keeping $\gamma(I)$ at $S^1$. But if $\gamma_2(I)$ lies in the unbounded component, it depends on the homotopy type of $\gamma_2$ I'd say. More precisely, if the induced map $f_{\star}$ on $H_1$ maps $[\gamma_2(I)]$ to $[t\mapsto 2e^{it}]$ your statement should be true.

Comment: Thus my guess would be: If $\gamma_1(I)$ lies in the bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\gamma_2(I)$ your statement should be true.

Comment: You could ofcourse also consider your curves in $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\star\}$. Then $\left(\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\star\}\right)\setminus\gamma_1(I)$ consists of two components wich are diffeomorphic! Thus you can get $\gamma_2(I)$ from the bounded to the unbounded component by alpplying a diffeomorphism. You should be able to choose that diffeomorphism in such a way that $\gamma_2(I)$ maps to $\{ x\ \big|\ ||x||=2\}$, by choosing $\phi^{-1}\left(\star\right)$ to lie "in the inside" of $\gamma_2(I)$.